# Can this MultiBranch Pipeline Groovy Snippet for the Jenkins Script Console beoptimized?

Tags: optimization, jenkins, groovy

I needed a little groovy code snippet that generates a MultiBranch Pipeline Project in a Jenkins 2.* Script Console. Didn't find it on the InterWeb, so I made it myself. Eventually I got it to work by glueing different code pieces together. 
I wonder if a groovy guru could help me optimize it and make it more beautiful? :-)

My further plan: Would be nice if I didn't have to manually enter the git repo. A scan over all repos in a git organisation would be nice.

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import jenkins.plugins.git.*
import hudson.triggers.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject
import jenkins.branch.BranchProperty
import jenkins.branch.BranchSource
import jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.*

def parent = Jenkins.instance
println "parent: $parent"

// create folder
Folder folder = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('poc')
if (folder == null) {
  folder = parent.createProject(Folder.class, "poc")
  folder.displayName = "P.O.C Jobs"
  folder.getProperties().add(
    new FolderLibraries(
      Collections.singletonList(
        new LibraryConfiguration(
          "pipelinejunit", 
          new SCMSourceRetriever(
            new GitSCMSource(
              null, 
              "ssh://git@servix/extra/git/poc_junit.git", 
              "local_git", 
              "*", 
              "", 
              true)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
println "folder: $folder"

WorkflowMultiBranchProject mbp = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('p_junit-lib_mb')
if (mbp != null) {
  mbp.delete()
}
mbp = folder.createProject(WorkflowMultiBranchProject.class, "p_junit-lib_mb")
mbp.displayName = "Junit Library [build/test *]"
mbp.getSourcesList().add(new BranchSource(new GitSCMSource(null, "ssh://git@servix/extra/git/poc_junit.git", "local_git", "*", "", false), new DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy(new BranchProperty[0])));
mbp.scheduleBuild2(0).getFuture().get()
println "mbp: $mbp"

def job
while (/* do */ {
  Thread.sleep(10)
  job = mbp.getItem('master')
  (job == null)
}());

println "job master: $job"
job.displayName = "Branch: master"
job = mbp.getItem('development')
println "job development: $job"
job.displayName = "Branch: development"

// reload jobs
parent.reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

> My further plan: Would be nice if I didn't have to manually enter the
>   git repo. A scan over all repos in a git organisation would be nice.

I think what you want is already implemented by the very popular [Github Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin.). From the [docs](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#github-branch-source): "The GitHub Branch Source Plugin allows you to create a new project based on the repository structure from one or more GitHub users or organizations. You can either: 1) Import all or a subset of repositories as jobs into the workspace from a GitHub user or organization or 2) Import a single repository’s branches as jobs from a GitHub user or organization." If you're not using either github or bitbucket, you wouldn't be able to use these awesome plugins, but hopefully you are. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks and I understand, since I use my on premise home server and a bare naked ssh git setup, I've to use my original idea with some kind of ssh shell/groovy magic (do a remote ls for repos, look for Jenkinsfile in the repo, and then use my code to do the project generation). Hmm, not to good, but a simple on premise setup is what I want, so thats what I've to do... 

Thanks anyway for the help and tip, I definitely will used it at work where we use github...